# Download a file via CURL with Cookies using php

Tags: php, cookies, curl, file-get-contents

I need to POST cookies.txt then download a page to a text file using CURL. This is my FGC example but apparently FGC is bad at cookies so I need CURL.

```
<?php
    $file = file('source\1.txt');
    foreach ($file as $link)
    {
        $link       = trim($link);
        $link2      = "http://site-that.com/authenticates?={$link}";
        $downloaded = file_get_contents($link2);
        $myFile     = "parsed/$link" . ".txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die('Cannot open file');
        fwrite($fh, $downloaded);
    }
    $timestamp = time();
    rename('source\1.txt', "source/done/done-{$timestamp}.txt");
    echo 'Finished';
```

Any ideas? Code examples would be extremely appreciated. A simple example that does this to like google.com would be great Also, if you have another way to do this that's faster, please post!

Comment: FGC is not bad at cookies. Also you probably want to use the search instead of asking the question, it's not specifically clear into which problem you run here. Code that shows how to do Cookies with both file_get_contents or curl exists en-masse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFileName); //$cookieFilename must be a path to a file with cookie data
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFileName);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);  //you may also use this, here $cookie is a cookie string
curl_close($curl);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: have not had time to check it yet, but they closed the question and you were the only answer, for your effort, you get the points =) I will try it out later, thanks!